# Supervised automatic photo library tagging

Tags: photography, machine-learning, tags

I am looking for an application that can offer the following functionality:

- Show an image from my photo library.
- Show several automatically suggested tags based on the content.

  - The photo should not be sent to a third party to derive the suggested tags.
- Allow me to accept/reject/edit/add suggestion.
- Store the accepted/added tags in the EXIF data of the photo.
- Move on to next photo in the "untagged" queue.

This would allow me to slowly tag and review my photo library during times I would otherwise mindlessly scroll away on various social media.

Ideally this would be a web application, that would connect to my central photo library such that I can tag/review that library both from my phone, as well as from my laptop.

I have tried the following software so far:

- Lightroom Classic: there are no suggested tags here
- [PhotoPrism](https://www.photoprism.app/):  no easy way to accept/reject tags; I need to jump through 2-3 panels. Also, the automatic suggestions are not very good.